# getting element offset from XMLReader

Tags: c#, xml

how's everyone doing this morning?

I'm writing a program that will parse a(several) xml files.
This stage of the program is going to be focusing on adding/editing skills/schools/abilities/etc for a tabletop rpg (L5R). What I learn by this one example should carry me through the rest of the program.

So I've got the xml reading set up using XMLReader. The file I'm reading looks like...

```
<skills>
  <skill>
    <name>some name</name>
    <description>a skill</description>
    <type>high</type>
    <stat>perception</stat>
    <page>42</page>
    <availability>all</availability>
  </skill>
</skills>
```

I set up a Skill class, which holds the data, and a SkillEdit class which reads in the data, and will eventually have methods for editing and adding.

I'm currently able to read in everything right, but I had the thought that since description can vary in length, once I write the edit method the best way to ensure no data is overwritten would be to just append the edited skill to the end of the file and wipe out its previous entry.

In order for me to do that, I would need to know where skill's file offset is, and where /skill's file offset is. I can't seem to find any way of getting those offsets though.

Is there a way to do that, or can you guys suggest a better implementation for editing an already existing skill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your XML into LINQ to XML's `XDocument` (or `XElement`), everything could become very easy.  You can read, edit, add stuff, etc. to XML files using a simple interface.

e.g.,

```
var xmlStr = @"<skills>
  <skill>
    <name>some name</name>
    <description>a skill</description>
    <type>high</type>
    <stat>perception</stat>
    <page>42</page>
    <availability>all</availability>
  </skill>
</skills>
";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

// find the skill "some name"
var mySkill = doc
    .Descendants("skill") // out of all skills
    .Where(e => e.Element("name").Value == "some name") // that has the element name "some name"
    .SingleOrDefault(); // select it
if (mySkill != null) // if found...
{
    var skillType = mySkill.Element("type").Value; // read the type
    var skillPage = (int)mySkill.Element("page"); // read the page (as an int)
    mySkill.Element("description").Value = "an AWESOME skill"; // change the description
    // etc...
}
```

No need to calculate offsets, manual, step-by-step reading or maintaining other state, it is all taken care of for you.

Comment: I'll start checking into linq to xml. I'm limited in my experience so it may take a few days to pick up the syntax, but as long as it provides a way for me to edit without overwriting I'll be happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it! In general, you can't reliably know anything about physical offsets in the serialized XML because of possible character encoding differences, entity references, embedded comments and a host of other things that can cause the physical and logical layers to have a complex relationship.

If your XML is just sitting on the file system, your safest option is to have a method in your skill class which serializes to XML (you already have one to read XML already), and re-serialize whole objects when you need to.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I'm a beginning level programmer. This particular program is for me and a small handful of friends, and for me to get some more learnin' in. I planned on looking at XElement to write back to the file, though I could just as easily position to before /skills, write all the new data, end with a new /skills (it's what I had to do in my low level programming class this term. Wrote our own pseudoXML parser-editor)

Answer (score 0):

Tyler,

Umm, sounds like you're suffering from a text-book case of premature optimization... Have you PROVEN that reading and writing the COMPLETE skill list to/from the xml-file is TOO slow? No? Well until it's been proven that there **IS NO PERFORMANCE ISSUE**, right? So we just write the simplest code that works (i.e. does what we want, without worrying too much about performance), and then move on directly to the next bit of trick functionality... testing as we go.

Iff (which is short for if-and-only-if) I had a PROVEN performance problem then-and-only-then I'd consider writing each skill to individual XML-file, to avert the necessisity for rewriting a potentially large list of skills each time a single skill was modified... But this is "reference data", right? I mean you wouldn't de/serialize your (volatile) game data to/from an XML file, would you? Because an RDBMS is known to be much better at that job, right? So you're NOT going to be rewriting this file often?

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I'm not concerned about performance at this point, I'm just trying to figure out how I can edit, say one skill without the possibility of overwriting another. I create individual objects from each skill so that when I get the GUI up(experimenting with that atm) I can have the user select a skill to edit from a list, display the info so they can edit it, then write it back to the file. I probably should have mentioned I'm a freshman in college and don't have advanced programming knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, so if there's no (known) problem with kust rewriting the complete list of skills to/from the XML-file then just do that. I was looking "underneath" what you where saying about rewriting parts of a text file using offsets, and thinking your motivation HAD to be efficiency, just misread your motives; for which I appologise... The answer remains fundamentally the same though... just do it the easy way, K?